# Outlook VSTO C# Make post to html url

Tags: c#, post, plugins, vsto, outlook-2010

I am making a plugin for Outlook 2010 using VS2010 C#.

The objective of my plugin is to grab the To, CC, BC from the new email when a
custom button is pressed from the ribbon and post it to an external url (which
takes in a post request). Similar to how forms in html/jsp can post inputs to
a different page(url).

So far, I can grab the To,CC,BC and store it in a string variable. But I don't
know how to make a post to the external url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code for my function so far:

```
public void makePost(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.MailItem myItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

    if (myItem != null)
    {
        string emailTo = myItem.To;
        string emailCC = myItem.CC;
        string emailBCC = myItem.BCC;

        if (emailTo == null && emailCC == null && emailBCC == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no recipients to check.");
        }
        else
        {
            string emailAdresses = string.Concat(emailTo, "; ", emailCC, "; ", emailBCC);

            //do something here to post the string(emailAddresses) to some url.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) / [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class, for example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com/postmesmth") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.Host = "google.com";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0";
string data = "myData=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Hello World!");


StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(data);
writer.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the idea. But I am running in one issue though. I am getting an error in the line 
'string data = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(emailAdresses);' 

It says HttPUtility does not exist in the current context. I did many imports including : using System.Net; using System.Web; Still no luck. 
Thanks

Comment: you need to add reference to System.Web.dll or use: Uri.EscapeUriString("Hello World!"); instead

Comment: Thanks. Uri.EscapeUriString worked. 
Now I am getting an exception error at line:
'HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;'

Debugger shows the response is getting null value. Could be something to do with the html page where I am posting it. 
Thanks.