# WebClient is blocked in an addin when used inside Outlook

Tags: c#, ms-office, webclient, outlook-addin

I am using C# to develop application plug-ins (e.g. Microsoft Outlook and etc).

To register the licenses of the plug-ins, I use WebClient to communicate to my database over the internet, by calling a php file on my server from the plugin that handles the registration.

This method works when the WebClient communication code is written in a single standalone Console Application program, or in a webform (not included in the plugin). But it does not work and breaks by the error "Cannot connect to server" when it is called within the plug-in itself through Outlook or other programs.

I guess this is a security issue that the plugin is blocked from communicating and sending out information to the Internet, either by the host application e.g. Outlook or the operating system security software.

So the questions are:

1. How can I enable the plugin called by another application to successfully communicated to the Internet using WebClient? (Run as Administrator or disable security are not suitable options).
2. What other better alternatives I have to call a php file on my server within a dll?

Comment: ***or in a webform***: or in a Windows Form Application

Comment: The other thread says you can do anything inside addin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579308/outlook-vsto-c-sharp-make-post-to-html-url

Comment: Thanks JesseJames. In fact, in my case it passes on some computers and breaks on some other. I guess some funny security suits block it. But the example you provided seems like a good one as it is imitating to send the request via FireFox, that may do the trick. Will try it. Thank you :)

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.